# Segmentation fault: 11 while running C program

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am trying to run the following code but I get Segmentation Fault after I enter the characters.

Anybody has any idea of what could be happening here?

I created two functions, one of them (palavra) gets one word out of a sentence and then the func compare_dicionario tries to find a matching word in a dictionary file.

The main function was built just to test these two functions, but it does not work after I enter the phrase...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000

int compare_dicionario(int tam, char pal[MAX]) {
    FILE * entrada_dic;
    int leitura, i, j=0, parar, achou;
    char pal_dic[MAX];
    entrada_dic = fopen("dicionario.txt", "r");
    while(leitura!=EOF && !achou) {
        parar = 0;
        achou = 1;
        for(i=j; !parar; i++) {
            leitura = fscanf(entrada_dic, "%c", &pal_dic[i]);
            if(pal_dic[i] == '\n') {
                i--;
                j++;
                parar = 1;
            }
        }
        if(tam == i) {
            for(i=0; i<tam && !achou; i++) {
                if(pal[i] != pal_dic[i])
                    achou = 0;
            }
        }
        else
            achou = 0;
    }
    fclose(entrada_dic);
    return achou;
}

void palavra(int n, int *m, int *l,char texto[MAX], char pal[MAX]) {
    int i;
    *l = 0;
    for(i=*m; i<n && ((texto[i] >= 'a'&& texto[i] <= 'z') || (texto[i] >= 'A'&& texto[i] <= 'Z')); i++) {
        pal[*l] = texto[i];
        *l = *l+1;
    }
    while(!((texto[i] >= 'a'&& texto[i] <= 'z') || (texto[i] >= 'A'&& texto[i] <= 'Z'))) {
        i++;
    }
    *m=i;
}

int main() {
    int n, i, cont=1, n_pal, m=0, tam, achou=0;
    char c[MAX], pal[MAX];
    printf("Entre com o tamanho da sequência de caracteres:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Entre com os caracteres:\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
            scanf(" %c", &c[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
        palavra(n, &m, &tam, c, pal);
        if(compare_dicionario(tam, pal) == 1) {
            achou++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", achou);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use a debugger to find out the erroneous instruction.

Comment: `while(leitura!=EOF && !achou)` <-- `achou` is not initialized in first iteration. And try `while( i<n && !((texto[i] >= 'a'&& texto[i] <= 'z') || (texto[i] >= 'A'&& texto[i] <= 'Z')))` instead of `while(!((texto[i] >= 'a'&& texto[i] <= 'z') || (texto[i] >= 'A'&& texto[i] <= 'Z')))`. Also, check the result of `fopen`.

Comment: can you recommend me one?

Comment: @CoolGuy neither is `leitura`.

Comment: On linux, use `gdb`.

Comment: i initialized it now and still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea, here:

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
    palavra(n, &m, &tam, c, pal);// here
    if(compare_dicionario(tam, pal) == 1) {
        achou++;
    }
}
```

Why do you use an address in a functions parameter, which adress later you assign to an iterator, your function expects a pointer give it to her.

```
for(i=*m;..
```

Read a few more things [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm)

Comment: I just wanted to keep track of where I am in the phrase, in order to catch all the words of the sentence. And every time I run the function I want to get the next word.

Comment: ok try this: Initialize all these int n, i, cont=1, n_pal, m=0, tam, achou=0; separately, and change the call to palavra to palavra(n, m, tam, c, pal);

Comment: I'm  thinking it tries to access the address of a pointer that does not exist most likely

Comment: just tried that and the error still occurs :/

Comment: added an modification look if it works

Comment: I found the problem! I was trying to access an invalid position of the vector. In the first for I set i=j, but j may not be a valid position